# Use parameter of a function as the key to get the value from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, undefined

I have a javascript/jQuery setup where a page name is given. A function should then take this, get the `html` data of the page and alert it.

HTML

```
var page = $(this).attr('id');
viewPage(page);

function viewPage(page) {
    var html = pages.page;
    alert(html);
}

var pages = {
    page1: 'Content of page.....',
    [etc...]
}
```

However, the variable `html` is always returning as undefined. When I manually access the page from the `pages` array it works fine. What's the issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `pages[page]` will work better or if id is a digit `pages["page"+id]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument has to be evaluated as a key of your `pages` object.

Try:

```
function viewPage(page) {
  var html = pages[page];
  alert(html);
}
```

When you use `pages.page` it looks for the key 'page'.  Wheras when you do `pages[page]` it evaluates your `page` argument to whatever it equals, and looks for that key on `pages`.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! I'll accept this when I can. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, `pages` is not an array, it's a javascript plain object.

Secondly, you need to use associative notation, not dot notation.

```
function viewPage(page) {
    var html = pages[page];
    alert(html);
}
```